# How can I export a component with children in ReactTS?

Tags: typescript, export, react-tsx

I import this component

```
import { someComponent } from './someComponent';
```

Then I declare a new component, that will be the child for the invoked one

```
const anotherComponent = () => {...};
```

I'm exporting it this way

```
export { someComponent(anotherComponent) };
```

but I'm receiving the following (not very helpful) error `Parsing error: ',' expected.`

Comment: `export const combined = <someComponent><anotherComponent></someComponent></anotherComponent>;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the good way to do it was

```
export const newVariable = someComponent(anotherComponent);
```

And I think the best option is naming the file like the exported variable ;)